IMAP not firing listener events from Node Server like I would expect
I am trying to write my own IMAP connection object because I'm getting errors from Google Gmail saying I have too many simultaneous open connections. I can't seem to capture events from even a very simple node program.
I'm expecting to see the "Disconnected from IMAP server" at the end of execution but I never do.  All I see is:
Connecting to IMAP server...
IMAP Connection successful

Here is my very simple code that is baffling me.
// use client

const Imap = require("imap");

interface ImapError extends Error {}

// Dummy IMAP configuration for testing purposes
const imapConfig = {
  user: "xxx",
  password: "yyy",
  host: "theimapserver",
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
};

async function testImapConnection(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      const imap = new Imap({
        ...imapConfig,
        //debug: console.log,
      });

      imap.once("ready", () => {
        console.log("IMAP Connection successful");
        imap.end(); // Request to end the connection
      });

      imap.once("end", () => {
        console.log("Disconnected from IMAP server");
        resolve(); // Resolve the promise here
      });

      imap.once("error", (err: ImapError) => {
        console.error("IMAP Connection error:", err);
        reject(err); // Reject the promise on error
      });

      console.log("Connecting to IMAP server...");
      imap.connect();
    });

    console.log("Successfully connected and disconnected from IMAP server.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to manage IMAP connection:", error);
  } finally {
    // Ensure the process exits after logging the final message
    console.log("IMAP test completed.");
    process.exit(0); // Use 0 for successful exit or another number for error states
  }
}

testImapConnection()
  .then(() => console.log("IMAP test completed."))
  .catch((error) => console.error("IMAP test failed:", error));


When I do enable the debugging, I do get the close message so I believe it is closing, but I still want to capture it in code.
<= '* CAPABILITY XAPPLEPUSHSERVICE IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CONDSTORE ENABLE QRESYNC QUOTA XAPPLELITERAL NAMESPACE UIDPLUS CHILDREN BINARY UNSELECT SORT CATENATE URLAUTH LANGUAGE ESEARCH ESORT THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES CONTEXT=SEARCH CONTEXT=SORT WITHIN SASL-IR SEARCHRES METADATA ID XMSEARCH X-SUN-SORT ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 X-UNAUTHENTICATE X-SUN-IMAP XUM1 MULTISEARCH IDLE X-APPLE-REMOTE-LINKS LIST-STATUS'
<= 'A2 OK Completed'
=> 'A3 NAMESPACE'
<= '* NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL'
<= 'A3 OK NAMESPACE completed (took 0 ms)'
=> 'A4 LIST "" ""'
<= '* LIST (\\Noselect) "/" "/"'
<= 'A4 OK LIST completed (took 1 ms)'
IMAP Connection successful
=> 'A5 LOGOUT'
<= '* BYE'
<= 'A5 OK !!'
[connection] Closed

